# Minimization of boolean function using Quine–McCluskey algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have a boolean row. It looked like this:

> Y = 0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0

Then I converted it to:

> f(x1,x2,x3,x4) = 0101 ∪ 1001 ∪ 1010 ∪ 1100

I divided it into groups:

> 0 | -
>
> 1 | -
>
> 2 | 0101, 1001, 1010, 1100
>
> 3 | -
>
> 4 | -

Then I should combine one minterm with another. If I'm not mistaken, theese minterms must be in separate groups (number of 1s) in order to combine them. But I don't understand how to do this.

How to finish minimization of this boolean function?

Comment: What boolean function?  I have no idea what you're trying to minimize.  Please explain.  Some context might be helpful too.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I had the boolean row (function) `Y` that should be minimized using using method of Quine–McCluskey. Or you need some other sort of info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I see what you're doing.  Your boolean function is 
$f(a,b,c,d)$ where $f(a,b,c,d) = 1$ for the four cases
$(0,1,0,1)$, $(1,0,0,1)$, $(1,0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise,
and you're trying to find a sum-of-products representation with as few
terms as possible.

Yes, in this case none of your terms can be combined with any other.
It seems there is no sum-of-products representation 
for this function with fewer than four terms.  And Espresso confirms that.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant by "what boolean function". You're right, it is `f(x1,x2,x3,x4) = 1`. If it is impossible to minimize no more that it is now, what should be the end representation of it or should it be left as it is now? And what is `Espresso`? TIA.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer

Comment: I also check it using Karnaugh Map. Yes, there's no possibility to minimize this function. Unexpectedly :)